# if statements execute even with false condition

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have problem with "if" block, it executes even with false condition. Method `Attack` destroy target gameobjects and it happened on second iteration of general loop, but code

```
Debug.Log(Player.Contains(Activepers[i]) && Activepers[i] != null);
```

in internal loop works 4 times and show in console `True,True,True,False`. How is it posible? If condition is false but it execute code and show that it is false?!

```
    for (int j = 1; j <= 15; j++)
        {
            mytext.text = "Round "+(j);

            for (int i = 0; i <= Activepers.Count - 1; i++)
            { 
                if (Activepers[i]!=null)
                { 
                if (Player.Contains(Activepers[i]) )

                { 
                        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
                        Debug.Log(Player[i]);
                        Debug.Log(Activepers[i]);
                        Debug.Log(Player.Contains(Activepers[i]) && Activepers[i] != null);
                        //}


                        Activepers[i].Attack(Activepers[i], Enemy[1], () =>
                                       { });
                }
                else
                {

                        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
                        Activepers[i].Attack(Activepers[i], Player[1], () =>
                                    { });
                    }

            }
            }
        }
    }

    Method Attack

    public void Attack(Characterbatle agressor, Characterbatle target, Action onAttackComplete)
        {

                Vector3 slideTargetPosition = target.Getpsition() + (Getpsition() - target.Getpsition()).normalized * 10f;
                Vector3 startingPosition = Getpsition();
                target.Damage(agressor.GetComponent<Perses>().damage, target.GetComponent<Perses>().armor,agressor.GetComponent<Perses>().chancecrit);
                if (target.healthsystem.IsDead())
                {
                **Destroy(target.gameObject);
                Destroy(target.kek.gameObject);**
            }

            SlideToPosition(slideTargetPosition, () =>
                {
                    state = State.Busy;
                    SlideToPosition(startingPosition, () =>
                    {
                        state = State.Busy;
                        onAttackComplete();
                    });
                });
```

Comment: Without knowing any more, its a little hard to tell, however.. your loop shows 3 debug log messages, so if the output is true, true, true (so first parse was true), then false.. it suggests whatever is in position 1 was false..... and stopped.. (although nothing in your code shows where that false would come from) Its also possible values are changing during execution

Comment: Your `if` line is different than your `debug` line. The `if` can be true and the debug `false` without being a contradiction.

Comment: Agree with BugFinder: Instead of just logging the pure bool value without any reference you should rather log like e.g. `Debug.Log($"Player[{i}] = {Player[i]}");` etc so you really see what's happening. Otherwise did you simply try **[debugging](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html)** your code line by line? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In following line:

```
Debug.Log(Player.Contains(Activepers[i]) && Activepers[i] != null);
```

you have two conditions: `Player.Contains(Activepers[i])` and `Activepers[i] != null`, the second one can be `false`, so it's logged as false.

You have `yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);` line before the `Debug.Log`, so the condition can be changed in runtime.